# Target parent array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

There is an array as follows:

```
myArray = [myObject1, myObject2, myObject4];
```

If I have access to myObject1{}, can I target it's parent array to count how many objects are in it?

Something like...

```
myObject1.parent.length??
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you have direct access to `myArray`?

Comment: The only way to achieve this is if you already have a reference to `myArray` somewhere. Then you'd have to check whether `myObject1` is contained in `myArray`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really need something like this, you could set the `parent` property yourself as you add objects to the array.

```
var array = [];
var obj = {}; // Or something else
obj.parent = array;
array.push(obj);
console.log(array[0].parent.length); // Will log 1
```

This will of course only work as long as you don't add the objects to more than one array at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

No. There's no "parent" relationship; not least because an object can be part of many arrays.

e.g.

```
var obj = {};
var array1 = [ obj ];
var array2 = [ obj ];
```

What should `parent` return?

Comment: Perhaps parent wasn't the correct choice of words on my part. I want a reference to the array in which the object is contained. In this case, the object is in a single array.

Comment: Replace "parent" in my answer with whatever word you like. The logic still stands. `obj` has no idea which (if any) array(s) it might belong to.